# Express Can't read property values of req.data in PUT request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have written a simple PUT service using express. Now when i call the PUT service and pass it the data i found something strange. When I read the data using req.data, i can see the data that I have passed. But when I try to go inside the property of req.data, I get an undefined.

Here is my app.js

```
module.exports = function (data) {

    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var routes = require('./routes/index')(data);
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var app = express();

    // all environments
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        res.set('X-Powered-By', 'Flight Tracker');

        next();

    });

    //CORS middleware
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:63018');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

        next();
    });

    app.put('/newflight', routes.create);

    return app;

};
```

Here is the flight

```
var Flight = function () {
    this.data = {
        number: null,
        origin: null,
        destination: null,
        departs: null,
        arrives: null,
        actualDepart: null,
        actualArrive: null
    };

    this.fill = function (info) {
        for (var prop in this.data) {

            if (this.data[prop] !== 'undefined') {
                this.data[prop] = info[prop];
            }
        }
    };

    this.triggerDepart = function () {
        this.data.actualDepart = Date.now();
    };
    this.triggerArrive = function () {
        this.data.actualArrive = Date.now();
    };
    this.getInfo = function () {
        return this.data;
    };

};


//Serving as factory to create instances of Objects

module.exports = function (info) {

    var instance = new Flight();    
    instance.fill(info);    
    return instance;

}
```

Here is my routes

```
module.exports = function (data) {

        var flight = require('../flight');

        for (var number in data) {

            console.log(data[number]);
            data[number] = flight(data[number]);
        };

        var functions = {};

        functions.create = function(req,res){
            if(!req.body) { 
                return res.sendStatus(400); 
            } else{
                console.log(req.body);
                console.log(req.body.number);
                console.log(req.body.origin);
                console.log(req.body.destination);
                var number = req.body.number;            
                data[number] = flight(req.body);
                console.log(data[number]);

                res.json({
                    status:202,
                    statusText:"Entries have been created",
                    data:data
                });
            }


        };

        return functions;

    }
```

I also have the output from the above create method:
[image]

Any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: Is `flight` a synchronous function?

Comment: Yes. I have updated the flight function code in question

Answer (score 0):

Basically my postdata was incorrect. I was passing postdata.data when I should be passing only postdata. This fixed the issue.
Also I added the 'Content-Type': 'application/json' in header.